# Is there way to hide the JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to hide or scramble/obfuscate the javascript code of a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734561/is-it-possible-to-hide-or-scramble-obfuscate-the-javascript-code-of-a-webpage)

Is there any way to hide the view of JavaScript code from the view page source action?

Comment: Yes, you can put your web server behind a firewall that disallows inbound traffic, and then turn it off and unplug it.

Answer (score 8):

No. You can [obfuscate](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Code-protection) it a lot, though.

Answer (score 4):

No. It is the same with any content on the web. If you can see or hear it, you can download it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you have sensitive algorithms or implementations, run them on the server and access them through Ajax or at the time the page is requested. Keep the javascript on your page UI-centric.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your js code to unexpert eyes using obfuscate techniques: [JS obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript) but an expert js coder can reverse engineering and understand it