# Hiding HTML5 Javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to hide or scramble/obfuscate the javascript code of a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734561/is-it-possible-to-hide-or-scramble-obfuscate-the-javascript-code-of-a-webpage)

Is there a way to hide the .js files to stop people from seeing the code and functonality behind. Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: You can't. Everything the browser sees, the user can as well.

Comment: Chrome has many tools that makes any "obfuscator" tools irrelevant. you can "prettify" javascript with the debug tools. If there is something sensitive in your code , do it server-side and use ajax to get the results. Everything that is on the client can be accessed and modified freely , there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

Obsfucators can be reversed using prettifiers, like BeautifulSoup.

If you don't want your source accessible by your users, use server-side code.

Comment: the layout can indeed be reversed but variable and function names will stay cryptic. That makes reading it very hard. You're right, though, that code that *really* needs to be hidden should be on the server.

Answer (score 1):

What do 'the JS files' you're referring to do at the moment? Depending on that, it may be possible to move certain functionality to server-side scripts which *are* hidden. The kind of code that you might want to be hidden is probably the kind that belongs server-side anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so because this way the browser can not see your code !

By the way, you can obfuscate your code, it is acceptable security.

Look at this : http://javascriptobfuscator.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try obfuscating it. It won't be hidden but it'll be mighty hard to read.

[This page has links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript) to various obfuscators.

Answer (score 0):

As the nature of client-side app is to be run on the client, you will never be able to hide your code from the clients.

One thing you *can* do is make it as hard to read and understand as possible. This is called obfuscation. There exist a couple JavaScript obfuscator, I suggest you make a Google search. [This one](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx) might not be the best but it can clearly show you how it's done. It converts this

```
var a="Hello World!";
function MsgBox(msg)
{
    alert(msg+"\n"+a);
}
MsgBox("OK");
```

To this

```
var _0xa6ca=["\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x57\x6F\x72\x6C\x64\x21","\x0A","\x4F\x4B"];var a=_0xa6ca[0];function MsgBox(_0xc324x3){alert(_0xc324x3+_0xa6ca[1]+a);} ;MsgBox(_0xa6ca[2]);
```