# Do I need the non-minified version of jQuery scripts in my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, deployment, minify

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3475024/57428) explain that for example `jquery-1.5.1.min.js` is a minified version of `jquery-1.5.1.js` and the latter is there so that I can read and analyze the script and the former is for actual use.

Now if I create an MVC3 ASP.NET application and add that into an Azure role both (and also `jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js`) are copied into the Scripts subfolder of the site and the service package.

Will I realistically ever need the `jquery-1.5.1.js` and `jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js` files in my site when debugging and in my Azure role when running? What are the scenarios when I might need them?

Comment: I find you don't really need the the non-minified version ever, unless you intend on debugging jQuery itself...but that's rarely the problem. The VSDoc one doesn't need to be linked in your HTML I think...it's just for intellisense, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While debugging I find it useful to use the non-minified version of jQuery when stepping through code.

It helps to see what's happening within jQuery that might be causing a bug. It really only comes into play if there's a bug in jQuery itself (I've found and reported a couple). If you're not interested in stepping through the jQuery code, then don't worry about the verbose versions, and stick to the minified reference.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I realistically ever need the jquery-1.5.1.js and
>   jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js files **in my site** when debugging and in my
>   Azure role when running?

No. There are better options:

- Keep a copy in your PC
- Bookmark the URL of one of the many mirrors of that jQuery version
- Download it again when needed (not really recommended, but better than <del>wasting</del> using space in your site)

This assumes the only purpose to need them in a future is for debugging