# getJSON typerror e is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have this jQuery below:

```js
$.getJSON('../GetCities?', { term: inputString }, function (data) {            
  var anchorTagElements = '';
  console.log("line 39 ");
  $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
    console.log("line 41 " );    
    anchorTagElements = anchorTagElements + '<a href=""><span class="searchheading">' +
      item.City + ', </span></a>';
  });
});
```

I can see the data is coming back from the server using firebug I can see the line 39 is printed to the log but line 41 is not meaning it failed right before the line 41 console.log

Error message I am getting is **TypeError: e is undefined**

[image: error message]

any ideas where to look at?

**EDIT**

Using jQuery non-minified I got:

> TypeError: obj is undefined
> length = obj.length,

It is failing while trying to get the length to evaluate `i`. I am not sure why I can see the data coming back correctly.

Here is the Data that comes back:

[image: data]

Comment: It seems the script is `minified` version. have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475024/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-js-and-jquery-min-js

Comment: What DON is saying, is that the `non-minified` version will give you error reporting that shows you where the issue occured. Using the `minified version` will only show you reference variables, makes debugging hard.

Comment: What is the value of `data.items`

Comment: I guess, it should be `$.each(data, function (i, item)`

Comment: can you post your response data?

Comment: its the screenshot that i have

Comment: I've posted my comment as answer. You are iterating `data.items` which is `undefined`. `data` is an array, loop through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {  
            anchorTagElements = anchorTagElements + '<a href=""><span class="searchheading">' +
                item.City + ', </span></a>';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$(data.items).each(function (i, item) {
```

Also, try printing `data` to see if it is valid.

Comment: actaully it didn;t hit the error and just skipped it it didn;t work