# What is the difference between the min and the regular file and which one should I use?

Tags: javascript, web, minify, qooxdoo

What is the difference between the normal and the min qoodoo js file?

Which file  should I use to write some js for my web browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between jquery.js and jquery.min.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475024/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-js-and-jquery-min-js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have exactly the same functionality.  However, javascript is often [minfied](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) to reduce the amount of code that is transferred from your server to your client's browser over the wire.  For debugging, the normal file may suit you better.  For production, the minified file (min qoodoo js) will be better because page loads will be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

`qooxdoo.js` - regular JS version
`qooxdoo.min.js` - minified JS version

By using `minified` version of files following advantages could be experienced.

- It will drastically reduce loading times and  bandwidth usage on your
  website.
- It also improves site speed and accessibility, directly
  translating into a better user experience.

Minification has become standard practice for page optimization

Basically the functionality is exactly the same except the readability hence better use `minified` version in your `PROD` environment and keep regular version for `debugging` purposes.