# Include both bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css or just one?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've added both the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css files and while debugging, I found that only one of them is being used while the other is being overwritten. I'm confused as to whether either of them has any additional features that I'm not using.  I'd also like to know whether bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js operate similarly.

Comment: refer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475024/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-js-and-jquery-min-js

Comment: Both are identical in content (the min is minified though) so you only need to include one version.

Comment: Oh ! i'm having several custom css and then bootstrap css too.this css have a style for almost everything and was messing with my own.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is correct behavior - you can have a single class named 'A' per document. .min.css/.min.js - are generally the same css and js files with all spaces removed from them. It makes them smaller and load faster. Browser won't need spaces anyway.

Comment: If that is the case why do we get both css files while downloading ? Just the min.css and js file would suffice ??

Comment: It's in case you were going to make edits to the original script/css, that you'd want the un-minified version. If all you're doing is including and making your edits somewhere else, then minified is smaller.