# What is the difference between bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**What should I use between bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.css?**

I am confused between the two files because `bootstrap.css` is readable i.e. scrollable up & down. But the `bootstrap.min.css` is hard to edit since you can only scroll it left and right.

Comment: I would suggest not editing bootstrap.min.css but instead create a new style sheet for your website/application, that can be used to override the styles in question.

Comment: Thanks @DrBeza, I'm now overriding.

Comment: I really recommend you taking a look here: http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include both bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css or any one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560454/include-both-bootstrap-min-css-and-bootstrap-css-or-any-one)

Answer (score 74):

`bootstrap.min.css` has been minified. This means all the whitespace and other extra characters have been removed. This is commonly done for use in production, to reduce the size of the file. When developing, it is usually helpful to use the unminified version, since, as you said, it is readable.

The way it works is that it takes all variables (for example `number`, `tableName`) and converts it to shorter names (in this example, it renames `number` to `a`, and `tableName` to `b`), so that the file becomes a little smaller (from **220 MB** to **219 MB**), that's essentially what it's doing, of course it does more, but this is one part where you can grasp what it does.

That's why there's no white spaces, because a whitespace takes up 0.1 MB and it's best without it.

EDIT: As mentioned by DrBeza in a comment, if your intention is to modify the `bootstrap.css` file, it is much better practice to create a separate `.css` file and add your own css rules that override the defaults. This way, if you update to a newer version of bootstrap, you can simply swap out the bootstrap files, instead of needing to edit the new `bootstrap.css` to move your modifications over to it.

Comment: Thanks! So it depends on the developer what they will use.

Comment: You typically "use" both.  Developers have various ways of using a non-minified version of a file during development for easy debugging and then changing the code to point to the minified file in production to reduce the transported file-size to the end-user.

Answer (score 25):

They have exactly the same function, but the `.min.css` version has been *minified*, meaning all whitespace has been removed to reduce file size and increase speed.

The normal `.css` is better for development if you want to edit and play around with the content, but if you are definitely not going to modify the file, use the `.min.css` for slightly better performance.

Answer (score 3):

The main diversity between bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css is spacing. In bootstrap.min.css file, All the white spaces has been removed where In bootstrap.css file, white spaces are there. So obviously file size will be larger as compare to bootstrap.min.css. For that reason, As a Developer, We should use bootstrap.min.css.

Answer (score 0):

The Gist is this:
Use bootstrap.css when developing, and use bootstrap.min.css when you're done developing (ie: change all instances in your code that points to bootstrap.css to bootstrap.min.css) for faster loading and better UX for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Use online Code formatter type in google or Bing like
Code formatter
[image]

it makes much better for scroll it left and right.