# What is defferent between bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently I learn Twitter Bootstrap. I am new now. When I download, I founded two CSS file.

```
1. bootstrap.css
and
2. bootstrap.min.css
```

But on sample file, only one file linked.like bellow:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

bootstrap.min.css,  Now I want to know:  What is defferent between bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css

Comment: `.min.css` is minified: excess whitespace is removed for improved size (and consequently improved load times).

Comment: Open them and you'll see.

Comment: bootstrap.css is the source code for someone to read and contribute if they choose to, bootstrap.min.css is the compact file which is recommended to use for your project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368456/what-is-the-difference-between-bootstrap-min-css-and-bootstrap-css)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference between the two.
The **'min**' simply means that it is minified, meaning white-paces, new lines and empty spaces are removed, so that the file is lighter for including in the HTML document.

which can result to shorter loading times. See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Answer (score 5):

The bootstrap.css file has line spaces, comments and is very structured.

The bootstrap.min.css has no line spaces, comments or structure.

A .min file is a file that is compressed to be smaller by removing comments and line spaces and should be use in your production version of your website/application to cut down on server and browser load.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

any .min.css File is the same .css file but minified ( that is what the min stands for) minified means that empty lines, white spaces, etc... are removed to make the file size smaller and improve the load time.