# Bootstrap Multiselect - conflicting CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I'm using this version of bootstrap for a web application:
http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/

In the docs, it says the css required is `bootstrap.min.css` which I have. The problem, however, is that my application and some of its elements (datetimepicker, etc) require `bootstrap.css`. I cannot have both loaded at the same time without conflicts. Currently, without loading `bootstrap.min.css` my multiselect looks like this:

[image]

And When I select multiple they go outside the label.

Is there a way I can get around this issue? Can I link the min version specifically to the instance of multiselect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368456/what-is-the-difference-between-bootstrap-min-css-and-bootstrap-css)

Comment: Or this one: [What is defferent between bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821442/what-is-defferent-between-bootstrap-css-and-bootstrap-min-css)?

Comment: Thank you for the link, I understand the difference, however when I load the minified version, the muliselecter looks different.

Comment: So maybe problem in versions of this bootstrap files? Do they have different versions? Could you use only bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: I'm using 4.3.1 on both the css files and the js files

Comment: Bootstrap multiselect is designed for Bootstrap 3. As stated [here](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/1015) currently there is no support for `v4`. The last commit was almost 2 years ago.

Comment: I have switched back to 3. Still having this problem