# Jquery tablesorter plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am a newbie to MVC. Please forgive me for this newbie question.  I am using JQuery table sorter plugin for sorting a html table. I am using [this](http://tablesorter.com/) tablesorter plugin. But this one doesn't seem to work.

My javascript code:

```
    <head>
                <title>Test Header</title>
              <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"</script>
              <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-latest.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        alert("hi");
                        $("#tab").tablesorter();
                    }
            );
                </script>
            </head>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <table id="tab" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                ---Header part---
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ---Body Part---
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to include the jquery library before the tablesorter js and just include one of the tablesorter js files

Comment: do you get the alert properly?

Comment: Yes. There isn't any issue with alert and now I have included the library also. Still no luck

Comment: than your browser must throwing some error. You can trace it through various tools. can u put the logs on here ?

Comment: right now it shows, you are importing two jquery libraries.

Comment: Yes, I have imported two libraries because in [this](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) documentation it was said to add two libraries

Comment: @ITppl I have tried in Mozila, Chrome and IE as well. It's working nowhere :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52212/discussion-between-it-ppl-and-debaprasad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include 2 tablesorter library. You need just one. You could include just the "jquery.tablesorter.min.js".

Look the difference between "file.js" and "file.min.js": [What's the difference between jquery.js and jquery.min.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475024/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-js-and-jquery-min-js)

And you also need to include jquery library.

Example:

```
<head>
    <title>Test Header</title>
    // Here you need to include jquery library
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tab").tablesorter();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

I have included these above libraries and removed everything else. Still it's not working :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the [jquery library](http://jquery.com/download/) before the `tablesorter.js` and just include one of the tablesorter js files

Comment: Included this following library, and followed your suggestions, Still it's not working 


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>