# What better - Jquery file from my SERVER or from URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

What better - Jquery file from my SERVER or from URL?
`<script src="jquery.js"></script>`
 or

`<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>`

Comment: QUESTION and Answer already exist ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475024/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-js-and-jquery-min-js

Comment: **[Read this post](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All too often, I find code similar to this when inspecting the source for public websites that use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.min.js"></script>
```

If you’re doing this on a public facing website, you are doing it wrong.

Instead, I urge you to use the Google Hosted Libraries content delivery network to serve jQuery to your users directly from Google’s network of data centers. Doing so has several advantages over hosting jQuery on your server(s): decreased latency, increased parallelism, and better caching.

Better use this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question.
If I need to load Jquery for lot of pages in my site, there is a way to load it once?

Comment: No. that not possible. But you can try this for. 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  document.write(unescape('%3Cscript%20src%3D%22/path/to/your/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E'));
}
</script>

**Fall back to local in case the CDN isn't available**

Comment: it'll be cached after first occurrence. So not to worry about that.