# date picker format jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I try datepicker  link [link datepicker](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx) ..   datepicker  and i try this code

```
<input  ID="fromdate" value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
```

when i try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#fromdate").datepicker();
        $("#todate").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
```

**UPDATE**

now the problem is i also use table for data and for this i use this please check link 
[data table](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx)
and i add these links for date picker and table

```
<%--
for date--%>
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript"   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<%--for grid--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In table link there is also css file

```
<link href="Styles/gridviewScroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

so when i remove css file datepicker work fine but when i add this css file then date picker look like this

[image: datepicker image]

Comment: Why you are adding two jquery js ?

Comment: which jquery????????

Comment: You are adding both jquery. min.js and jquery.js actually both are same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475024/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-js-and-jquery-min-js

Comment: u mean these 2.. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: which i remove ???

Comment: use either google api or jquery api remember dont use both the api at a time it will affect the performance also misbehave the functionality.

Comment: i use jquery api. so which one i remove from code

Comment: remove google api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine.

Check the following js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hLx9808w/

```
<input  ID="fromdate" value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />

$(function () {
    $("#fromdate").datepicker();
    $("#todate").datepicker();
});
```

It may be caused due to any jquery ui css override.

The issue with table structure css.

Comment: i have these links .. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: <%--datepicker--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: <%--for grid--%>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/gridviewScroll.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/gridviewScroll.css"/>

Comment: Can you add your header links section with formatting

Comment: Your above two comment not having the full links and also not readable.
So post your complete head section code in your questions description.

Comment: Can you post css from this file "Styles/gridviewScroll.css", some css properties from this style sheet causing the issue

Comment: If possible post that in the css section of https://jsfiddle.net/hLx9808w/ this js fiddle

Comment: It is still working fine. Add complete css from that style sheet.

Comment: this is complete css

Comment: Then put the html code with wrapper class 'GridviewScrollHeader' contains the date picker input

Comment: Your css is causing the issue, but without complete html I am also unable to help you. Because it is working fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: when i try your css this does not work ..  i try to apply that css in jquery like this ..   $("#tabledata tr:first").addClass('GridviewScrollHeader');
                     $("#tabledata tr").addClass('GridviewScrollItem');