# How to version javascript and css files as part of a powershell build process?

Tags: powershell, versioning

I'm using [servicestack/bundler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler) to combine and minify my js & css files from within a powershell build script.

As a part of this build process I'd like to find the resulting javascript and css files in my `_Layout` file, and append a querystring version automagically.

For example

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/app.min.css?v=1")" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/app.min.js?v=1")"></script>
```

becomes

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/app.min.css?v=2")" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/app.min.js?v=2")"></script>
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this in powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out, and have uploaded the solution to [github](https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/Powershell-Snippets/blob/master/version-javascript-css.ps1). I've chosen to use an MD5 hash within the file name [instead of appending a querystring parameter at the end of the file](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/). The reason for this is because of some proxy's not caching files with querystrings.

This solution also does NOT version files if they have not changed.

Here's the solution with comments for readability.

```
#region Variables
    $directoryPath = Split-Path ((Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value).MyCommand.Path   # directory the script is running from (document root)
    $jsFilePath = "assets\scripts\"                                                  # scripts path will end with trailing slash "\"
    $cssFilePath = "assets\css\"                                                     # css path will end with a trailing slash "\"
    $jsFileNameRegex = [regex] '(nameOfYourProject\.).*(\.min\.js)'                  # myApp.asdf1234.min.js
    $cssFileNameRegex = [regex] '(nameOfYourProject\.).*(\.min\.css)'                # myApp.asdf1234.min.js
    $filesContainingVersionedResourceRefs = @("$directoryPath\index.html")           # array of files to search for script/css references
#endregion


#region Functions

# Function which versions javascript and css files using the content hash.
# NOTE: this assumes that you have two "default" versions of your combined files
#    nameOfYourProject.css/js
#    nameOfYourProject.min.css/js
function versionResource($fileToVersionRegex, $filePath){

    # Gets the default file name from the regex
    $defaultFileName = $fileToVersionRegex.ToString() -replace "(\()|(\))|(\\)|(\*)", ""
    $defaultFileName = $defaultFileName -replace "\.\.\.", "."

    # Gets the content of the default file and creates a hash
    $fileContent = Get-Content $filePath\$defaultFileName
    $md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $utf8 = new-object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($fileContent)))
    $versionHash = $hash.Replace('-', '')

    # Creates a new file name based on the content hash
    $newFileName = $defaultFileName -replace "\.min", ".$versionHash.min"

    # Tries to get the old versioned file name
    $fileToVersion = Get-ChildItem $filePath | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $fileToVersionRegex}
    if($fileToVersion -ne $null) {
        $oldFileName = $fileToVersion.Name
    }

    # $newFileName is still just a string at this point.
    # If the new version name doesn't match the old version name,
    # then we know that we need to update everything to the new version.
    if($oldFileName -ne $newFileName) {

        # OPTIONAL
        # remove the obsolete version of the file to be versioned
        # You may choose to NOT remove the versioned file, however
        # since it "should" be in your version control, you can roll back if necessary
        if($fileToVersion -ne $null) {
            Remove-Item $filePath$oldFileName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }

        # rename the default file with the new file name
        Rename-Item -literalPath $filePath$defaultFileName -NewName $newFileName

        # loop through all of the specified source files and replace with the appropriate versioned file
        foreach($private:file in $filesContainingVersionedResourceRefs){
            $fileContent = Get-Content $private:file
            Clear-Content $file

            if($oldFileName -ne $null){
                # replace the old version string if it exists
                $newFileContent = $fileContent -replace "$oldFileName","$newFileName"
            } else {
                # replace the default version string if it exists
                $newFileContent = $fileContent -replace "$defaultFileName","$newFileName"                
            }

            Add-Content $private:file $newFileContent

        }
    }

    # OPTIONAL: remove original files
    # this just keeps your directory clean and free of unneeded versions of the css/js
    $private:nonMinifiedVersion = $defaultFileName -replace ".min", ""
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $filePath$defaultFileName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $filePath$private:nonMinifiedVersion -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}

# version the Javascript
versionResource $jsFileNameRegex $jsFilePath


# version the css
versionResource $cssFileNameRegex $cssFilePath
```

Comment: Proxies won't magically cache your resources unless you set the appropriate HTTP caching headers. Adding a hash to the file name is only one part of the solution. Don't forget about HTTP headers max-age and Cache-Control.

Comment: @VincePanuccio this obviously goes without saying. For me, this is implemented in my asp.net web.config, but others will implement it however they need to. This answer is about how to version javascript, not how to cache javascript.